# Bootstrap 4 Equal height columns not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two columns next to each other but the content inside them is different but the columns are different I was lead to believe this was default it bootstrap 4 or it was in one of the alphas at one point.

Currently I have tried.

```
.equal {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.equal > [class*='col-'] {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

and added that to my css.

and my html looks like.

```
<div class="row equal">
    <div class="col-md-8"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

but it doesnt seem to affect it in any way.

edit seems like its not the column but the content inside said column that isnt 100% of its parent.

but if i do height: 100% it makes it 100vh for some reason and not 100% of the column height.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBEegO

in this i have made divs inside it i need them divs 100% of the parent column

[image]

that is the current view of the row and column the border is on the inner div of the column.

I need it so if there is more content in the left column the right column is the same height as it and if the right column is as it is on the image the left column gets its height.

Comment: Works fine here - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/vaPrLp Perhaps you should demo the rest of the code.

Comment: sorry just worked out its the div inside the column that isnt the height of the column. how do i make that the right height

Comment: This has already been answered before. Use the `h-100` class on the inner div. Also, Bootstrap 4 rows/columns are flexbox by default so there's no need to add all the custom CSS for flexbox. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LBareO

Comment: that makes my column and row go 100vh for some reason i dont know why same as height:100% as everything is dynamic height so it just puts it to 100vh

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

For div inside that, you can use position absolute with CSS transform and translate property.

```
.innerdiv {
 top: 50%;
 position:absolute;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This will make your inner div verticle and horizontal center.

Comment: It's flexbox... so there's no need for this - to align middle `display:flex; align-items: center;`

Comment: Thats not what I am trying to achieve at all. I need the inner div of both columns to be 100% height and width of the row based off of the column with the most vertical content

Answer (score -2):

I have updated the codepen please check https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBEejz?editors=1100

```css
.equal div div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.equal>[class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row equal">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div>
      <p style="background-color:pink;">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis quibusdam nobis praesentium hic vero quo quia error sed commodi cumque, illo porro eaque ad ipsa. Error maxime consequatur officiis alias fuga mollitia quas, magnam delectus necessitatibus
        illum, quos aperiam doloremque eaque explicabo architecto dolor? Placeat quos nemo natus velit aliquam?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci blanditiis commodi sapiente totam sequi consectetur provident. Voluptatibus corrupti odit reiciendis, aliquid temporibus dolores tempore optio delectus nesciunt ipsam veritatis quisquam
        facilis voluptatem voluptates inventore aliquam, praesentium, assumenda ducimus ratione quasi nisi sunt consequatur corporis soluta. Deleniti quam harum soluta alias minima voluptas iusto voluptates, iure necessitatibus assumenda ex. Minus numquam
        beatae vero aperiam cupiditate assumenda ipsam hic ad corporis placeat facere consequuntur consectetur sint, aspernatur mollitia optio odit eos officia nostrum? Totam asperiores quia sequi autem. Ex nostrum fuga, et, illo iusto inventore officiis
        facere minima hic sint obcaecati consectetur.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do have content on my site but it is dynamic and pulled from an api. still should work though

Comment: Not sure if you have any further question on it, please explain in more detail.

Comment: i edited my question take a look at the image ive uploaded that shows my issue, also your code doesn't work

Comment: You want to have inside divs too equal height, so notice the above p, which has less content but is being taking full height of the div. does it what you mean parent height 100%?